# FileIOPermission.GetPathList throws exception?

Tags: c#, file-permissions, argumentexception

I'm using FileIOPermission, and it's throwing an error on me:

```
FileIOPermission fileIOPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, folderName);
string[] paths = fileIOPerm.GetPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess);`
```

Error is:

> ArgumentException was unhandled - Must set exactly one flag.

I Googled this, there's no info anywhere for this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess.aspx) documentation

> Append , Read, Write, and
>   PathDiscovery access to a file or
>   directory. AllAccess represents
>   multiple FileIOPermissionAccess values
>   and causes an ArgumentException when
>   used as the access parameter for the
>   **GetPathList** method, which expects a
>   single value.